# reactjs importing imported JSON object into array-list

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, arraylist

I can display a JSON object that I get with redux.
but when returning, the list is empty.
How do I transfer a JSON object that I send into list as

payload: 
    return {
        type: USER_INFO,
        payload: {
            profile: list
        },
}

```
export const USER_INFO = 'USER_INFO';

let list = [];

export function userAction(newValue) {

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/me", {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("id_token")}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
    .then((response) => response.json() )
    .then((responseData) =>{
        list = JSON.stringify(responseData);
        console.log(list);
       // console.log(JSON.parse(liste));
        return list;
    });

**//list appears empty when I check here**
**console.log(list);**

return {
    type: USER_INFO,
    payload: {
        profile: list
    },
}
}
```

Comment: API calling is an asynchronous code, your function is returning before you get the response

Comment: Please first learn how async programming works in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I handle asynchronous requests with Redux.

I'll have actions for each type of status the user info action could have. For example, there's three states of the user info request: default, loaded, and failed.

```js
const userInfoRequest = () => { type: USER_INFO_REQUEST };
const userInfoLoaded = (userInfo) => { type: USER_INFO_LOADED, userInfo };
const userInfoFailed = (error) => { type: USER_INFO_FAILED, error };
```

You're going to need to turn the `userInfo` action into a thunk so that the action can property handle its internal asynchronous state inside the action creator.

```js
const userInfoRequest = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(userInfoRequest());
  fetch(...)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => dispatch(userInfoLoaded(result))
    .catch(error => dispatch(userInfoError(error))
}
```